# Yammer REST API with Authorization Bearer AccessToken returns 401 UnAuthorized

Tags: c#, authorization, c#-5.0, yammer, http-status-code-401

I am trying to use the Yammer REST API to get messages. The first part of the process in getting a OAuth token is successful. I am doing something wrong in the way the oAuth token is passed while retrieving messages as I get a 401 UnAuthorized.

```
    //Create the HttpClient to the Yammer Access Token
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
            string query = string.Format("https://www.yammer.com/microsoft.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=rhIwJiPokWcaUZAR2VpgZg&redirect_uri=http://www.msn.com", queryToken);

            HttpResponseMessage yammerAuthTokenResponse = _client.GetAsync(query, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;

//if response is successful, capture the Yammer token
 if (yammerAuthTokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
 string HTMLYammerAuthCode =      
 yammerAuthTokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 strYammerAuthToken = GetYammerAuthToken(HTMLYammerAuthCode, strYammerAuthToken);
 Console.WriteLine(strYammerAuthToken);
}

//I get the YammerAuthToen and store it in strYammerAuthToken 
//I then try to get messages using this token

string queryReadMessages = "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/my_feed.json";
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", strYammerAuthToken);

HttpResponseMessage yammerAuthTokenResponseReadMessages = _client.GetAsync(queryReadMessages).Result;
```

This produces a 401 UnAuthorized error

Answer (score 1):

Change

> string queryReadMessages =
>   "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/my_feed.json";

to

> string queryReadMessages =
>   "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/my_feed.json";

All API calls should be directed to the api.yammer.com domain.